# Executing method inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am receiving a warning when trying to execute a method inside a Fragment.

```
public class PrimaryFragmentDormir extends Fragment {

    // Declare Variables
    ListView listview;
    List<ParseObject> ob;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary_layout_dormir,null);

        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
       // setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        // Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
issue here==>        new RemoteDataTask.execute();
        //test commit dell
    }

    // RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Custom ListView Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create the array
            worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
            try {
                // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                        "Country");
                // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
                // by ascending
                query.orderByAscending("ranknum");
                ob = query.find();
                for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                    // Locate images in flag column
                    ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("flag");

                    WorldPopulation map = new WorldPopulation();
                    map.setRank((String) country.get("rank"));
                    map.setCountry((String) country.get("country"));
                    map.setPopulation((String) country.get("population"));
                    map.setFlag(image.getUrl());
                    worldpopulationlist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(PrimaryFragmentDormir.this.getActivity(),
                    worldpopulationlist);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    }
```

I have searched for a solution, but I am not able to solve the issue.

Thank you

Comment: What does the warning say? That should point you towards the issue.

Comment: @Tanis.7x, the warning says: Cannot resolve symbol 'execute'

Comment: What warning? Also you shouldn't show dialog inside onCreateView there is plenty better fragment's life-cycle callbacks for this...

Comment: Typo?... Java use new operator with () () () () () () () please delete this question as it is off-topic

Comment: @Selvin, thank you, but the question is not solved.

Comment: @Selvin, may be you are right, I do not know Java at all, if I where a Java expert I wouldn't ask for help in SO. Don't waste your time with my question if you don't want to help me or you don't know how to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it me or your code cannot compile because the line

```
new RemoteDataTask.execute();
```

cannot be reached ? It's right after a return.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary_layout_dormir,null);
    // ...
    new RemoteDataTask.execute();
}
```

Secondly, as it has been mentioned, you need parenthesis to create a new object :

```
new RemoteDataTask().execute();
```

Try something like this :

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary_layout_dormir,null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have changed it as you propose, and no success either.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is a little off here:

```
new RemoteDataTask.execute();
```

When you instantiate an object with `new`, you need parenthesis like so: `new RemoteDataTask()`.

Your error says "cannot resolve symbol 'execute'", because the `execute()` method doesn't exist as a static method on the `RemoteDataTask` class, and even if it did it wouldn't work with the `new` operator.

Thus you want to change that line to:

```
new RemoteDataTask().execute();
```

Comment: Thank you, I have changed it as you propose, and no success either.

Comment: No, now it says: Unreachable

Comment: Thank you Tanis, I have it now.